# Javascript After AJAX Request

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

When the page is loaded, the function `commentsShowHideEffect` in javascript runs. When  ajax request is made all instructions in the method `commentsShowHideEffect()` are gone. How to recover these isntructions or call `commentsShowHideEffect()` method again after ajax request ?

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        commentsShowHideEffect();
    });
</script}

 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MessageButton" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="RefreshTimer" runat="server" Interval="500" />
            <asp:DataList ID="ChatDataList" runat="server" >
                <ItemTemplate>    
                    <td><asp:Label ID="lblRaterName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Text")%>'></asp:Label></td>
               </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
     </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind [Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager endRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383810%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event which will fire after the ajax request is completed by the update panel.

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
     alert("After ajax call ended");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the commentsShowHideEffect out of the jQuery scope:

```
<script>
    function commentsShowHideEffect() {
        //do something
    }

    $(document).ready(function (){
        commentsShowHideEffect();
    });
</script>
```

Further I prefer to use the document.ready syntax, because it is more clear for the programmer to understand what it is.

Comment: But when AJAX refresh the ContentTemplate all isntructions in function  "commentsShowHideEffect" don't work anymore. How to make them work again after the request is made ?

Comment: Could you clarify in your question, what you mean with instructions?

Answer (score 1):

You did not mention jQuery in you question and not in the tags either.
But you code sees to suggest that you are using it, so here is a link to a relevant doc page :

http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

In your situation, this should work :

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings) {
   commentsShowHideEffect();
});
```

Note that the above will trigger for each and every ajax request. If you want more control, you should use the complete or success callback on the individual requests.